# Concatenate two tensors of different shape

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, pytorch, embeddings

I have two tensors:

```
a.shape = (1, 30, 1220) # represents text embedding vector (30 spans, each with embedding size of 1220)
b.shape = (1, 128, 256) # represents image features obtained from a pretrained CNN
```

1. How do I concatenate everything in `b` to each one of the 30 spans of `a`?
2. How to concatenate the whole `b` to the whole `a`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate these two arrays, because their shapes don't match.
You could concatenate them if you had:

1)

```
    a.shape = (1, 30, 1220)
    b.shape = (1, 30, 256)
```

2. 

```
    a.shape = (1, 30, 1220)
    b.shape = (1, 128, 1220)
```

or eventually

3)

```
    a.shape = (1, 30, 1220)
    b.shape = (1, 128, 30)
```

4. 

```
    a.shape = (1, 30, 1220)
    b.shape = (1, 1220, 256)
```

Comment: Can I flatten the image feature vector and then concatenate with text feature vector?

Comment: @Sid  If that data still makes senses to you. Because until now, text embedding and image feature are treated differently in your model.